# How to Query in MongoDB using one Key in c

Tags: c, mongodb

I am attempting to search for a key's value in MongoDB via my .c program. essentially In my collection in one of my documents: I have key:value, i want to be able to return said value by passing in the key. I have seen

```
 query = bson_new ();
 BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "hello", "world");

 cursor = mongoc_collection_find_with_opts( collection, query, NULL, NULL);
```

I want to be able to search using only hello and return world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query a value in MongoDB, with only one key and pair (ex. Key:Value). Regex can be used.

```
bson_t *query;
bson_append_regex(query, key, -1/* length of key*/, ".", NULL);
cursor = mongoc_collection_find_with_opts(collection, query, NULL, NULL);
```

The string "." in regex signifies 'any string', thus if you would need to find json value within another key such as:

```
{ key:
      {
       second_key:value
       }
 }
```

Changing the Regex to "second_key." would locate desired value.  
**Note**
This will return any other values that may lay within, paired with  mongoc_cursor_t *  you can select the desired value you are looking for.